# Create IoT Alert in Dynamics 365 Field Service from Azure IoT Central

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-iot-central

I have an Azure IoT Central Application with a rule alert. When a rule is triggered, I would like to create an IoT Alert in Dynamics 365 Field Service. The documentation available in Microsoft is outdated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/field-service/cfs-iot-overview.

The power automate template in the photo is not available:
[image]

And the Dynamics Create a new record is not available as well:
[image]
Is there a more updated document to do this?

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? You need to elaborate more on what is not working.

Comment: I updated my issue. The template and the Dynamics create a new record is no longer there in the options